# Visual Studio Code удаленная отладка через ssh

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code удаленная отладка через ssh. Имеется доступ к ubuntu через ssh c windowds машины необходимо редактировать html файлы с подсветкой синтаксиса? Notepad ++ совсем грустно что то делать большое, желательно использовать Visual Studio Code, может есть расширение для нее?

Comment: Почему не использовать SCP?

Comment: Тут придется копировать файлы постоянно туда обратно что слишком замедляет работу

Comment: большие файлы что ли? Notepad++ как иначе файлы открывает?

Comment: Привычным редактором пользоваться удобнее всегда настройки одни и те же, а тут разные. Да и подсветка синтаксиса разная

Comment: Поставь WinSCP чтобы редактировать удобнее с авто пересохранением

Comment: я спрашивал как будто notepad++ не копирует туда обратно?

Comment: Использовать редактор, поддерживающий SCP, например Comodo Edit

Comment: Это не отладка, а просто редактирование HTML